# Saving data from uitableview to core data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, uitextfield

I have a UITableView with two different text fields in it for text entry. Is there a way to loop through the entire tableview and either save it to core data or copy the results to an array and then save it to core data. 
Here is the code to create my tableview cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Add Terms to New Set";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
questionTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 250, 30)];
questionTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
questionTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//questionTextField.placeholder = @"Put Question Here";
questionTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
questionTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[questionTextField.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[questionTextField.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
[questionTextField.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[questionTextField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[questionTextField setEnabled: YES];

answerTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400, 10, 250, 30)];
answerTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
answerTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//answerTextField.placeholder = @"Put Answer Here";
answerTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
answerTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;

[answerTextField.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
[answerTextField.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
[answerTextField.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
[answerTextField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];


[answerTextField setEnabled: YES];

[cell addSubview:questionTextField];
[cell addSubview:answerTextField];
return cell;
```

}

How do I loop through the tableview and add the question text and the answer text to an array or save straight into my core data modal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should adopt a different strategy for saving your data.  Instead of depending on the views (i.e. cells) to hold onto it, you should put it into a backing array as soon as the user enters it.

You don't say how many total rows you're going to show but, if there's scrolling, you're almost guaranteed that there will be fewer cells than rows because of caching and that information entered will be lost when the cell comes back around again.

For the same reason, you shouldn't be adding fields to cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` unless `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` returns nil...the cached ones already have those fields.